# Non-SDK interface: Is using getter disallowed?

Tags: android, android-activity

as of Android 11 using mParent from Activity.java is on the list of greylisted (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/test-changes aka banned) things.  The relevant line from the article is below:

Landroid/app/Activity;->mParent:Landroid/app/Activity;   # Use androidx.fragment.app.Fragment and androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager instead.

However, does this mean I cannot use the corresponding getter, Activity.getParent() ? I imagine the getter would be fine, just not changing the variable, because if the getter was banned then they would list that explicitly (as they list other getters) but the comment to use Fragment or FragmentManager is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

`getParent()` [is a `public` method on `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Activity#getparent). You do not need reflection to use it, and you can call it on every Android version.